# iptables for local connections

Tags: iptables, localhost

On "Server A", I have a service running on port 1445.
"Server B" can connect to "Server A" on port 445 via the following rule:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d www.kunde.de -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1445

This does not work for connections initiated on "Server A", i.e. local connections. What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d www.kunde.de -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1445

Because locally originated packets go through OUTPUT, rather than through PREROUTING.

Answer (score 0):

if you use lxc or other virtualization technology, you redirect all traffic from port 445 to container's 1455.

The local request in Server A will not pass `PREROUTING`. The reason was addressed before. Local traffic will not access `nat table`, but if you use DNAT before, it only works for outer traffic to Server A, `REDIRECT` only worked for port forward, it can not be used as `DNAT`

Comment: Most of this is either factually incorrect or inaccurate. Please consider reworking this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should better read some manuals and docs.

Anyway brief chains description:

```
* “PREROUTING”: Packets will enter this chain before a routing decision is made.
* “INPUT”: Packet is going to be locally delivered. (N.B.: It does not have anything to do with processes having a socket open. Local delivery is controlled by the “local-delivery” routing table: `ip route show table local`.)
* “FORWARD”: All packets that have been routed and were not for local delivery will traverse this chain.
* “OUTPUT”: Packets sent from the machine itself will be visiting this chain.
* “POSTROUTING”: Routing decision has been made. Packets enter this chain just before handing them off to the hardware.
```

And take a look here:

[Netfilter packet flow](http://clip2net.com/clip/m17268/1259352160-clip-92kb.png)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables)